# iOS9 Storyboards Auto Layout

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am trying to make my app's storyboard universal for all Apple devices.  I am having an issue with auto layout for some of my views.  I am considering making a storyboard for each device since I think it will look better in the end, since I would be able to size my fonts and buttons differently for each type of screen.

What would you guys recommend I do?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the real question is how to solve the issues with some of your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach would be to use **autolayouts** and **size classes**. This approach would allow you to create only single storyboard for both iPhone and iPad. And you can easily size your fonts for different devices and also make buttons/views position/size differently for different screen sizes using size classes.

Comment: Ok I will have to check size classes out

Answer (score 2):

You should use size classes in which "any width , any height " is best for all layouts .

Comment: What if I wanted to set logic in the app delegate that displayed different storyboards based on whether or not the screen is a certain size. Wouldn't this be easier?

Comment: In both cases you will need to manage the things so its up to you ....in size class case you will need to manage the content ratio programmatically or you should create different storyboard for different layouts ...

Comment: Also using size classes you can have addaptive layout in same storyboard.

Comment: Haha if it really doesn't matter I'll probably just create multiple storyboards because I'll spend hours messing with the constraints otherwise.

Comment: Yeah using multiple storyboard is new trend now...:)

Comment: Yeah I think auto layout is great for simple view controllers, but once you start making them more complicated auto layout becomes a pain in the neck

Answer (score 1):

AFIK you can't just use size classes to determine the screen size and then set font sizes based on that. As can be seen when you edit in Storyboards, you can set the font sizes for specific size classes eg. compact, regular etc. but not iPhone 5, 6 or 6+. If you are wanting different font sizes for different screen sizes you could use UIAppearance to style your text elements in a centralised way or create IBOutlets to the UI elements and set the font size or other properties as required. With either of these you may still need to check the screen size with something like this:

```
switch UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width{
case kIphone6PlusWidth:
    label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)
case kIphone6Width:
    label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(18)
default:
    label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(14)
}
```

Alternatively, separate storyboards for each will give you customisability but will lead to a fair amount of duplication with laying out the UI elements in different storyboards.

Comment: Yeah that's similar to what I'm doing